# Is it possible to add post-install commands to top level Makefile generated by CMake?

Tags: cmake

CMake generates something like the following for the install rule:

```
# Special rule for the target install
install: preinstall
        @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
        /usr/local/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install
```

What I want to do is have some custom commands executed after `cmake_install.cmake` is invoked so it looks something like:

```
# Special rule for the target install
install: preinstall
        @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
        /usr/local/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
        post_install_command_1
        ...
        post_install_command_n
.PHONY : install
```

I can do what I want using `add_custom_command(TARGET ... POST_BUILD ...)` for things that we have written (6 - 10 macros to update). However, there are a bunch of third-party things that get installed and I really don't want to add `POST_BUILD` custom commands for all of them (currently 19 projects with more to come and it can be tough to identify what needs to be processed after building instead of after installing). I think it would be much easier to maintain if the custom commands are only used in one place (i.e. as last part of install handling) and where I know they will do everything that is necessary.

Is it possible to get CMake to add commands to the top-level Makefile's install rule?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `SCRIPT` or `CODE` variant of the [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#script) command. If you put the required commands in a script `PostInstall.cmake` in the project root directory, add the following call to your outermost `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
install (SCRIPT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/PostInstall.cmake")
```

`install` commands are added to the `cmake_install.cmake` script in order, thus the call should be added to the end of the `CMakeLists.txt` to have it run after all other installations have completed.

Comment: Thank you! I swear that I tried something like this and it didn't work. Tried it again and it appears to work. Guess I must have had a typo (or something) that kept it from working.

Comment: This doesn't work for my build with sub-directories. The end of the outermost CMakeLists.txt is executed before all the cmake_install.cmake's are included from the sub-directories.

Comment: Little tricky, especially regarding specifying sub-directory install paths and targets from the root, but eventually got it working.

Answer (score 9):

To add a post install step, you need to add a directory at the top level CMakeLists.txt. You must have a directory with a CMakeLists.txt in it in order to set up the post install steps to be executed last in the install.

The first step is to add variables and values to be used by the post install script. None of the variables available during the build will be available post install, so everything you need must be set up here.

In the top level CMakeLists.txt, after all previous add_subdirectory commands have been executed, add something like this.

```
# Workaround for the lack of post_install steps.
# add_subdirectory is executed in order, this one must be last.
if(CMAKE_PROGRAM_PREFIX)
    # Make sure this is the LAST directory added.
    add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/postinstall)
    # Add any variables you need during post install.
    install(CODE "set(CMAKE_PROGRAM_PREFIX \"${CMAKE_PROGRAM_PREFIX}\")")
    # Add any properties to your post install.
    get_property(PROGRAM_PREFIX_FILES GLOBAL PROPERTY PROGRAM_PREFIX_FILES)
    install(CODE "set(PROGRAM_PREFIX_FILES \"${PROGRAM_PREFIX_FILES}\")")
endif()
```

Now we have variables, and properties converted to variables available to use at post install.

Next we need a CMakeLists.txt file in the postinstall directory. Cmake will execute this file at the end of the build. At that time we install a SCRIPT that does the work during post install.

```
# CMake will execute this last in the build.
# Install the script that does the post install work.
install(SCRIPT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/postinstall/ProgramPrefix.cmake")
```

Now we will get control during post install in ProgramPrefix.cmake. CMake will add the variables we have set earlier.

```
# Make sure this was requested.
if(CMAKE_PROGRAM_PREFIX)
    # CMake builds a manifest of all files it has installed.
    foreach(file ${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_FILES})
        # Make a list of installed files to compare.
        get_filename_component(nm ${file} NAME)
        list(APPEND fileindex ${nm})
    endforeach()

    # Process program prefix files.
    foreach(nm ${PROGRAM_PREFIX_FILES})
        list(FIND fileindex ${nm} efound)
        # Did we match a manifest file with our list of files?
        if(NOT efound LESS 0)
            # Process the file.
            program_prefix_file(${efound})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endif()
```

There is a little more work to actually do the program prefix, but this framework will let you execute cmake commands after everything has been installed.

Comment: I don't understand the stuff about program prefix. Is that relevant? Or just a random code example of how you can run a script at post-install?

Comment: I wanted to add a program - prefix function like autoconf has in a tree that supports both autoconf and cmake builds. Program prefix is just the example. The cmake  post install step can be used for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Most of you probably won't like this answer, but I've been trying to figure this out all day and the cleanest solution I could come up with to just get the library runtime DLL's into my install directory alongside my executable were these two lines of code:

```
file(GLOB runtime_dlls LIST_DIRECTORIES false ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.dll)
install(FILES ${runtime_dlls} DESTINATION bin)
```

This is notably a Windows solution, and I'm sure it will be somewhat different for Linux/MacOS.