# In CMake, how to run a script after targets get installed?

Tags: installation, cmake

I am trying to run a script after CMake install completes. I found [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998679/is-it-possible-to-add-post-install-commands-to-top-level-makefile-generated-by-c), but it still does not work, because my script depends on the installed targets.

Basically my script gets ran before the targets are installed. This is because CMake seems to put the code which installs the targets of sub-directories at the end of `cmake_install.cmake`

Here is an example that illustrates the problem; the sub-directory CMake file:

```
# src/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION bin)
```

The top-level CMake file:

```
# Top-level CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory(src)
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ls ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/foo)")
```

Running `make install` yields:

```
-- Install configuration: "debug"
ls: cannot access /tmp/dummy/bin/foo: No such file or directory
-- Installing: /tmp/dummy/bin/foo
```

Any idea how I can work around this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you found that cmake places sub-dir install targets to the end of the cmake_install you can just add another sub-dir with cmake containing what you need to be done after all other targets.

Comment: This works, but there needs to be more on passing lists from the generate step to the install step executed later.