# How to generate files during install?

Tags: cmake

I have a script that makes an empty directory and downloads some files to it (it may also do some verification on them). These files need to be installed.

I can't do the download during the build step, because it's a bit heavy.

So, I'd like to do it on the install step or on the CPack step. How to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with `install(SCRIPT)`? Just create cmake-script, which performs actions you need, and pass it to that command. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998679/is-it-possible-to-add-post-install-commands-to-top-level-makefile-generated-by-c.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, it ends up under `if(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT`, but I've got components.

Comment: Installation script doesn't have access to variables defined in the project. For access to CPACK variables it needs to use `include(CPACK)`. BTW, as there are problems with install script, it would be better to include its code (in minimal form) into the question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, there are problems because I use per-component CPack. When it's per-component - all `install(SCRIPT)` are ignored by CMake. (as for solution: I had already a manual post-pack step, so added the script there)

Comment: Please, edit the question and describe your concrete problem.