# How to execute cmake add_custom_command after target "install"

Tags: linux, cmake, linker, installation, rpath

I have a Software which is installed under `/opt/my_program/`. Now I want to write a plugin for it. `my_program` consists of mutliple libraries and binaries, that every user of the system can use.

```
[user@pc:/opt/my_program]$ tree
├── bin
│   └── mp
└── lib
    ├── lib_foobar.so
    ├── mp_lib.so
    └── other_lib.so
```

The provided `/opt/my_program/lib/mp_lib.so` links against `/opt/my_program/lib/lib_foobar.so`. Now my plugin needs `mp_lib.so` to use another (ABI-compatible) version of `lib_foobar.so` which I deploy with my plugin. I dont want to modify the original lib, because not every other user of the system may need/have the new version.

#### My idea was the following:

- I build my plugin as usual
- I install it to `CUSTOM_WORKSPACE`
- while installing my_plugin, I now copy `mp_lib.so` into the `CUSTOM_WORKSPACE/mp_lib_custom.so` as well and do link my plugin against `CUSTOM_WORKSPACE/mp_lib_custom.so`
- then I do copy `lib_foobar_new.so` into `CUSTOM_WORKSPACE` as well

This allows every other user, to use the regular `my_program` as is, and only the users that use `my_plugin` do have their own workspace with their own `mp_lib_custom.so`, and their own `lib_foobar_new.so`:

CMakeLists.txt

```
...
set(CUSTOM_WORKSPACE "workspace")
set(MY_PROGRAM_DIR "/opt/my_program")
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/my_plugin.so DESTINATION ${CUSTOM_WORKSPACE})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_config.txt DESTINATION ${CUSTOM_WORKSPACE})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib_foobar_new.so DESTINATION ${CUSTOM_WORKSPACE})
install(FILES ${MY_PROGRAM_DIR}/lib/mp_lib.so DESTINATION ${CUSTOM_WORKSPACE})
...
```

output:

```
[user@pc:/tmp/workspace]$ tree
.
├── my_plugin.so
├── my_config.txt
├── lib_foobar_new.so
└── mp_lib_custom.so
```

- `my_plugin.so` links against `./mp_lib_custom.so`
- `mp_lib_custom.so` links against `lib_foobar_new.so`
- therefor that I copied `mp_lib_custom.so` out of `myprogram`-installed dir, its `RPATH` is not correct anymore

#### Problem

Now I need to patch the `mp_lib_custom.so`'s RPATH with a custom-command AFTER `cmake install` was called (because otherwhise the copy wouldn't exist yet).

I tried it with:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET install POST_BUILD
  COMMAND "chrpath" "<ARGUMENTS>"
  COMMAND "echo" "file-was-patched")
```

But somehow I seem to misunderstand something, or "install" is not a CMake-Target?!

Comment: "'...install' is not a CMake-Target?!" - Yes, CMake doesn't provide `install` as a common target. For perform additional actions during installation stage use `install(CODE)` or `install(SCRIPT)` command flows.

Comment: Hmz, I expected that. And how to I make sure, that `install(SCRIPT)` is being executed **after** the other `install` commands?

Comment: CMake respects the order of `install()` commands in the `CMakeLists.txt`. See that question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998679/is-it-possible-to-add-post-install-commands-to-top-level-makefile-generated-by-c

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I'll give `install(SCRIPT)`  a try

Comment: Yeah you are right. My question seems to be a duplicate. Sorry, I haven't found the other answer. Thanks for pointing that out :)
This can be closed then